# How to create function that checks if react ref is not null using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I haven example using react and refs:

#### This works:

```js
refTable = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
if(typeof refTable !== 'function' && refTable !== null && refTable.current) {
  console.log(refTable.current);
}
```

#### This fails

```js
type shapeAllowRefs = React.RefObject<HTMLElement>;
const allowRef = (ref:shapeAllowRefs):boolean => (typeof ref !== 'function' && ref !== null && ref.current ? true : false);

const refTable = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
if(allowRef(refTable)) {
 console.log(refTable.current);
}
```

#### Error:

--- Argument of type 'HTMLTableElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.

I have created an example in typescript playground and it works there using similar concept but unfortunately I cannot replicate the problem above. It seems to be a problem with react refs.

#### Equivalent simpler example - works

```js
type shapeX = null | {
  current: string
} | (() => void);

const allowRef = (ref: shapeX): boolean => (
  typeof ref !== 'function' && ref !== null && ref.current ? true : false
);

const obj:shapeX = { current: 'john' };
if (allowRef(obj)) {
  console.log('obj = ', obj);
}
```

any ideas why it fails using - if(allowRef(refTable))

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do these extra checks? `React.RefObject` returned by `React.createRef` is an object, not a function. Just check if `.current === null`

Comment: nevertheless it fails without that check

Comment: Can you provide type definitions for React.RefObject<T> and for React.createRef<T>() from index.d.ts?